# Pandas replicate one column from a row to a column in multiple rows in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe(df1) with one row

```
text   val1 val2
"test" 3    2
```

I have this dataframe(df2) with many rows

```
text   val5 
"this" 1   
"is"   2
"test" 3
```

I want to create a new column in df2 and put value from first dataframe in this new column 'val2'

```
text   val5 val2
"this" 1    3
"is"   2    3
"test" 3    3
```

I've tried this code above.

```
df1['df2'] = df1['df2']
```

But, the value appears just in one row like this

```
text   val5 val2
"this" 1    NaN
"is"   2    NaN
"test" 3    3
```

How to make this right?

Comment: Does `df1` always have 1 row? `val2` in `df1` is 2. Where does 3 come from? What's your logic here?

Comment: Just one selected column, or all columns that don't already exist?

Comment: Looks like you're grabbing val1 from df1 but want to label it val2? Without any join logic, it would be: `df2['val2'] = df1['val1'].repeat(len(df2)).values`

Comment: Looks like a `bfill()` on `val2` after your `df1['df2'] = df1['df2']` would work.

Comment: To get what you show in the third code-section: df2["val2"]=df1["val1"].values[0]. If its now what you mean, try to explain it differently

Comment: @harvpan - You don't know, got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have tried the same in different manner. Try the below code :

```
mask = (df2['text'] == df1['text'][0])

import numpy as np

val2 = []

for data in mask:
    if data:
        val2.append(df1['val2'][0])
    else:
        val2.append(np.nan)

df2['val2'] = val2
```

Now if you look at the dataframe it will only be have value where it matches the value of the column.

```
Ouput:

    text    val5    val2
0   this    1   NaN
1   is      2   NaN
2   test    3   2.0
```

I hope this help.